# PowerApps embedded in Power Bi Desktop communication to Local SQL Server without on Premises

Tags: powerbi, powerapps

I have created a Power app in the Power apps portal. This power app communicates to one of my databases via an on-premises gateway. On a button click on the power app embedded in the Power BI Desktop, few selected data is passed as a parameter to a procedure which runs in my database.

I am using this power app embedded in my Power BI Desktop template.

Power BI Desktop -> Power Apps -> DB (via on Premises Gateway)

Power app works only with the internet.

Is it possible to make power app communicate to my local database without any network connections? (without on-premises or cloud databases)

If no, then is it possible to redirect the power app communication to the appropriate db gateway by passing the parameter(gateway name) from Power BI Desktop from which the request originated?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, PowerApps doesn't work offline today. It won't be able to talk to your local database without network connection.

You can direct PowerApps to talk to the appropriate data gateway. Make sure you install the gateway from PowerApps portal first. Then create a connection using that gateway to your local database. Then use that connection in your PowerApps to talk to your database (read/write to your local database).

Hope this helps!